# BS4 and scraping an updating table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the links to all of the players of the EPL from whoscored.com ( Link in variable root below ) 
here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
root = "https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6335/Stages/13796/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2016-2017"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(root)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
players = soup.find("div", {'id':'statistics-table-summary'})

print(players)
```

If you go on the page you will see a list of players and a next button to display the next 10 players ( of which there are 284 in 29 pages)
My desired output: save links to each ten players profiles and then move on to next page with the next ten players untill done

to do this I thought I would do `soup.find_all('a',{'class':'player-link})`
as the links and name of player are in a container like this, but this returns none. so I thought I would first find the table with all in there but this returns none too. Any light on this ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: print page source and see what you have - some people has problem with JavaScript on PhantomJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the table to be loaded before getting the `.page_source`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

driver.get(root)

# wait for at least one player to be present in the statistics table
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#statistics-table-summary .player-link")))

page = driver.page_source
driver.close()

# ...
```

Comment: thanks man, that is it, but one more question. How do I get past the problem of the next button not having a href to sart this process again for the next ten, do I change the condition in wait.until?

Comment: @entercaspa glad it worked! Please create a separate question about the "next" button handling - I have some thoughts, will post them there. Comments are not convenient enough for it. Thanks!

Comment: done my friend, I eagerly await your response, I am quite intrigued as how to sidestep the next button, I have never had to scrape a website with this kind of updating table before